# Scrapy Item Loader

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a spider that extracts business hours and it works fine. How ever I am not able to hide the item values that were passed on to another item dict not show again in the final out put. Can some one help me in this

my item file:

```
mon = scrapy.Field()
tue = scrapy.Field()
wed = scrapy.Field()
thu= scrapy.Field()
fri= scrapy.Field()
sat= scrapy.Field()
sun= scrapy.Field()
businessHours=scrapy.Field()
```

My Spider

for list in listings:

```
il = MySiteLoader(selector=details,item=WrapListItem())
        il.add_xpath('mon','.........')
        il.add_xpath('tue','.........')
        il.add_xpath('wed','.........')
        il.add_xpath('thu','.........')
        il.add_xpath('fri','.........')
        il.add_xpath('sat','.........')
        il.add_xpath('sat','.........')
        il.add_value('businessHours',{"Mon":il.get_output_value('mon'),"Tue":il.get_output_value('tue'),"Wed":il.get_output_value('wed'),"Thu":il.get_output_value('thu'),"Fri":il.get_output_value('fri'),"Sat":il.get_output_value('sat'),"Sun":il.get_output_value('sun')})
```

my Current out put is

mon: 10 AM - 6 PM
tue: 10 AM - 6 PM
wed: 10 AM - 6 PM
thu: 10 AM - 6 PM
fri: 10 AM - 6 PM
sat: 10 AM - 6 PM
sun: 10 AM - 6 PM

Business Hours :{mon: 10 AM - 6 PM
tue: 10 AM - 6 PM,
wed: 10 AM - 6 PM,
thu: 10 AM - 6 PM,
fri: 10 AM - 6 PM,
sat: 10 AM - 6 PM.
sun: 10 AM - 6 PM}

What I need is only

Business Hours :{mon: 10 AM - 6 PM
tue: 10 AM - 6 PM,
wed: 10 AM - 6 PM,
thu: 10 AM - 6 PM,
fri: 10 AM - 6 PM,
sat: 10 AM - 6 PM.
sun: 10 AM - 6 PM}

Please help